# Why is the lower leaf wilted on all of these plants? Should I remove them?

Tags: plant-health, basil, wilt

These basil plants have been thriving steadily better and better since being transplanted as sprouts.  However every one of this group of 8 in the end of a planter is exhibiting a wilted leaf, and it's always the lowest one.  What's going on here?  Should I snip off these wilted leaves?

[image: Basil more or less thriving]
[image: Lowest leaf wilted on all my basil plants.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those are just the oldest leaves and I'd just snip them off...otherwise, they look very healthy!

Comment: Leaves age and go out of production, they kind of clog internally, wither and drop off normally. Removing them just gets them off the plant before they can become diseased.